# Is there a way to load a fully functional Menu Bar without PHP?

Tags: jquery, html, content-management-system

I'm currently trying to put the menu bar of my HTML Webpage into a separate file without using php.

How do I set this up properly?

Using a php file is not an option because of the CMS I'm using (http://www.coast-cms.de, German only). Therefore I needed to do it without Include. I almost got it to work the way I want it to by using `jquery.load`.

The navigation bar is loaded correctly, but the dropdown menu in it won't open until I reload, or on some pages won't work at all.

I suspect this has something to do with the order the scripts are loaded in, but given my limited experience with jQuery I was neither able to find out how to sort the loading process, nor which order would have been correct.

```html
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<div id="navbar"></div>
<script>
  $("#navbar").load( "/modules/navbar.html");
</script>
```

I expected to be able to just paste another html file into my existing one before anything else happens, but my code seems to load the file at some other point.

EDIT:
I'm using jquery.dropotron for the submenu https://github.com/ajlkn/jquery.dropotron

navbar.html

```html
<header id="header">
               <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">Company Name</a></h1>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="submenu">X</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="a.html">A</a></li>
                                <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
                                <li><a href="d.html">D</a></li>
                                <li><a href="e.html">E</a></li>
                                <li><a href="f.html">F</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="ueber_uns.html">Über uns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="g.html">G</a></li>
                        <li><a href="h.html">H</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#FOOTER">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
```

EDIT 2:
The code that I think is used for the hamburger menu in main.js

```js
a('<a href="#navPanel" class="navPanelToggle"></a>').appendTo(b);
        a('<div id="navPanel"><nav>' + a("#nav").navList() + '</nav><a href="#navPanel" class="close"></a></div>').appendTo(d).panel({
            delay: 500,
            hideOnClick: true,
            hideOnSwipe: true,
            resetScroll: true,
            resetForms: true,
            side: "right"
        });
```

Comment: Can you share the `navbar.html` code, or at least a minimal version without any personal/company info? Do you have any JS that works on `#navbar` after the code you showed above? Is the dropdown in question a simple `<select>` with no additional JS, or is it a custom dropdown like selectmenu or Bootstrap's Dropdown?

Comment: Sorry, I should really have provided that information right away. Added it now. I'm using jquery.dropotron for the submenu.(https://github.com/ajlkn/jquery.dropotron)
I also added the navbar.html code in the original post.

Comment: The code where you include `dropotron.js` and call `$('#nav ul').dropotron()`, is that within your `navbar.html` file or somewhere after the `.load` call in your first page? If you do something like `$('#navbar').load('/modules/navbar.html', function() { $('#nav ul').dropotron(); });` does that seem to alleviate the issue?

Comment: What you suggested did resolve the issue, but I'm very rarely getting two Dropdown menus now.
As to the location where it is supposed to be called I'm not 100%, I'm new to JS and working with a template I bought.  
I found the following in main.js, which is loaded on the end of the main page, though:
        ```a("#nav > ul").dropotron({
            alignment: "right",
            hideDelay: 400
        });```
Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: My guess is that originally, that code would occasionally run after the `load()` call to import the HTML, which would make the dropdown work properly, but would sometimes run before the `load()` call finished - and therefore didn't find the `#nav ul` element, since it wasn't loaded yet. Now, it still runs before and after, but the callback method I suggested in my previous comment always runs - so it occasionally makes two dropdowns on the same element. I'm unfamiliar with your CMS; can you edit `main.js` and comment out that `dropotron()` line, or is that file not something you can edit?

Comment: I actually managed to somewhat fix it by adding ```{
            alignment: "right",
            hideDelay: 400
        }``` to the code you provided.
I guess my question is solved, then, although I'm not 100% sure if I just made the second dropdown invisible by laying the first one right on top of it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Having read your comment now (typed mine while you were typing, too): That was exactly the problem. I combined what I did with removing the line from the .js file, now everything works like it was intended. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The problem was just the order in which the scripts were loaded. 
What fixed it was making sure main.js (in which both the dropdown and the hamburger menu were activated) was not loaded, before the entire page had finished loading.

I achieved that with the following code:

```html
<script>$(document).ready(function() {$.getScript("assets/js/main.js");});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To "summarize" our comment discussion for others who may encounter this issue - the problem was the dropdown menu script (using `jquery.dropotron`) was originally occasionally running before the element was loaded by AJAX and occasionally running after (in other words, sometimes the element was loaded by AJAX fast before the parser got to the JS that called `dropotron` in the `main.js` file, and sometimes it was loaded after).

When the `dropotron` call was called before the element was loaded by AJAX, it failed to find anything to attach to, so it didn't do anything. When it was called after the element was loaded by AJAX, it found the element and was able to generate the dropdown (hence the navbar sometimes working and sometimes not working).

To alleviate this first issue, you confirmed that using a callback to create the dropdown after loading it did, in fact, always produce a dropdown:

```
$('#navbar').load('/modules/navbar.html', function() { 
  $('#nav ul').dropotron(); 
});
```

However, then the issue then became that it was being called twice in certain situations - this was due to the `dropotron` line being called in `main.js`, in the same fashion as originally, where sometimes it would run before the AJAX completed and sometimes after; when it ran after, it created a second menu.

The final solution was to comment out the line in `main.js` to remove the second call, and just use the AJAX callback to ensure that `dropotron` was called after the element was loaded.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I think this wasn't the full fix. The error doesn't come up often (maybe 1 time out of 20), but it still occurs from time to time.
```html
index.html:61 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropotron is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (index.html:61)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```
To me this sounds like the script ist run before something is loaded. Also I noticed the Hamburger menu for small devices is missing from time to time, too. Do you think it could be possible to force main.js to be loaded at the right moment?

Comment: Fixed the new dropdown problem by moving the loading of dropoton into <head>, but still didn't figure out how to fix the hamburger menu

Comment: I was going to suggest that the JS wasn't loaded in the correct order. The best way I have used to include scripts is to load them all in order at the end of your HTML, just before the `</body>` tag. So it should be `<body><!-- other HTML --><script src='jquery.js'></script><script src='dropotron.js'></script><script> /* CUSTOM CODE */ </script></body>`. That way, you know all your HTML is loaded first (except things you load by AJAX), and you know your scripts are in order (dropotron should come after jQuery, since it relies on it - and custom code should come last if it uses either).

Comment: As for the hamburger menu, I haven't used `dropotron` myself, but I'll take a look, and see if I can spot what's going on. Do you have any errors when the hamburger menu doesn't appear?

Comment: I'm not quite sure the hamburger menu uses dropotron, but I added the code which I believe is the one used for the hamburger menu from main.js the to original post. 
There are no errors when the Hamburger menu doesn't appear

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue, which would generally warrant a second question on SO. In the code you updated with, it uses `$('#nav').navList()`, but I'm not sure what the `navList` function is, or what it does (I could make a guess, but I'd rather not just guess). I also don't know what the `b` and `d` variables are set to. I would advise figuring out what `navList` does, where it comes from (is it part of another jQuery library?), and find what `b` and `d` are set to, then post a new question with that information and as much info as possible about cases when it does and doesn't appear.